# Wörterbücher für Fachsprache / Dictionaries for terminology in specific domains

Tags: dictionary, technical-terminology

LEO und Co sind zwar für den allgemeinen Wortschatz ganz gut zu gebrauchen. Wenn es aber an die Übersetzung von technischen Dokumentationen geht, helfen sie einem nicht wirklich weiter.
Man könnte die Fachbegriffe zwar sinngemäß ins Deutsche übersetzen, meist existieren jedoch schon (zumindest in dem Fachbereich) etablierte Begriffe, die dann zumindest auch genannt werden sollten. Gemeint sind hier Termini aus aktuellen Forschungsbereichen, zu denen es erst wenige deutschsprachige Publikationen gibt.

Daher nun meine Frage: Gibt es (möglichst frei im Netz verfügbare) Wörterbücher für Fachsprachen?

---

Sites like LEO are appropriate for translating common language into German. When it comes to technical terms in a scientific domain they are not appropriate. One could translate terms literally or analogously but often there are already German counterparts used in few German publications.

Are there (free online) dictionaries for those kind of lingo?

Comment: Da die Frage nicht so konkret gestellt ist (für mich wäre der Bereich Informatik/Datenbanken interessant), wäre die Frage als Community Wiki wohl am besten aufgehoben.

Comment: Suchst du ein Deutsch-Wörterbuch oder ein Englisch-Wörterbuch?

Comment: Englisch->Deutsch wäre am besten. (fast alle Papers in En verfaßt) Zur Not ginge auch rein Deutsch, dann müßte man den Bereich aber schon recht genau eingrenzen können.

Comment: Wenn es sich nur um einzelne Wörter handelt nutze ich in der Regel Wikipedia, d.h. suche in der Wikipedia der einen Sprache nach dem Begriff und schalte dann auf die andere um.
Aber dort wirklich was zu finden, was den aktuellen Stand der Forschung wiederspiegelt wird natürlich schwer.

Comment: In meinem Bereich finde ich in der englischen Wikipedia meist nur Stubs oder Weiterleitungen auf unschärfere Begriffe - oft aber auch gar nichts. Es kommt leider nur selten vor, daß der englische Begriff dann auch einen entsprechenden deutschen Eintrag hat.

Comment: I think it's better to add the English version of the question, so that it's easier to find an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a confident and up-to-date source, use one where *several* authors and experts contribute to a discipline. This is mostly a compendium, handbook, encyclopedia. I would not trust very much an internet source here. A handbook is a current mirror of all discussions in the scientific community written by experts. Mostly up-to-date and corrected in following editions.

**Either you make correct translations or use English technical terms and a German glossary at the end of script**. I would do the latter as informatics is mainly English whereas for disciplines like math/physics lots of good detailed German coursebooks exist because of long tradition and history of these disciplines in Germany. Even some [German terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_German_expressions_in_English#German_terms_common_in_English_academic_context) are common in English scientific language.

How to decide if you should translate *run time, thread, webdesign* into German? What terms are Germans already more used to? You would have to reason and find out for every single term. Even some Wikipedia translations don't seem appropriate/not really used by Germans.

Stick with well known English terms and make a glossary. Here you can translate/describe terms in a small sentence much easier and more accurate as by a uncommon/self-defined German slang term.

http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/
http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/it_handbuch/
http://foldoc.org/

Some dictionary/glossary from my bookmarks list for computing. **Esp. look how the "Handbuch für Fachinformatiker" solves your problem**.

Comment: The glossary of "Handbuch für Fachinformatiker" only uses well-known terms, most of them with an own entry in the German wikipedia. Some of them aren't even well explained: "Race Condition Wettstreit mehrerer Prozesse um eine Systemressource."

Comment: @mbx yeah imo more aimed toward hobby-developers than computer scientists, but written by a computer scientist. Your problem is that there are only very few german publications - so basically there cannot be common german technical terms!? See? So use the ones you know, for the others use the english common ones and a glossary. If a technical term is accepted by the majority, you can find it in a handbook/review article. A single technical term in very few cited publications is per se no common term and not worth to translate but has to referenced "author calls it ..." - then glossary entry.

Comment: I didn't mean common german technical terms. I meant terms, that are commonly used _in a specific domain_ eg. terms used in the domain of (multimedia databases|sensor network routing)

Answer (score 2):

Weniger bekannt, aber vielleicht doch von Interesse sind die verschiedenen Thesauri und Vokabularien, die von den EU-Institutionen für Übersetzungen quer durch alle Fachgebiete genutzt werden. Im [Europäischen Justizportal](https://e-justice.europa.eu) gibt es eine [Zusammenstellung der drei gebräuchlichsten, frei verfügbaren Glossare](https://e-justice.europa.eu/contentPresentation.do?idTaxonomy=119&plang=de&vmac=Jv_yDa_dt-ggrQhizKnmg-3c1vQXssBoBk4M5ddCyt9cgDSSSu1TLfEylLT1bXxyXeK3d3fsjqsQeoIYDSYvDwAAGrMAAAJ0#). Zwar kommt mir - jedenfalls im juristischen Bereich - der Umfang noch etwas mager vor, aber ich nehme an, dass das Angebot noch wachsen wird.

Answer (score 2):

Für die Mathematik gibt es auf der Website der Deutschen Mathematikervereinigung [Informationen](http://www.mathematik.de/ger/information/fremdsprachen/englisch.html), mit einer kurzen Liste und einem Hinweis auf ein [Onlinewörterbuch](http://www.henked.de/maple/dictionary.htm).